# I'm not able to read my matrix dynamically

Tags: c

My program crashes when it comes to the reading function, at the `scanf` line. What can I do?

I'm guessing it's an issue with the way I wrote `(*(a + i) + j)` but I can't tell.

```
void read(int **a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (*(a + i) + j)); //Access violation writing location 
        }
}

void show(int**a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", *(*(a + i) + j));
        }
}


int main()
{
    int n,opt,a;
    printf("number of lines and columns:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = (int**)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));
    while (1)
    {...
```

Comment: ```malloc```, on success, returns a ```void``` pointer or ```void *```. You have declared ```a``` as an automatic ```int``` variable.

Comment: its a square matrix, equal number of rows and columns

Comment: But I don't see a matrix declared in your source code.

Comment: Either declare a *two dimensional array*, or an *array of pointers*, and then initialise each pointer to a dynamically allocated *row*.

Comment: `int a; a = (int**)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int))` This is a good example why you should not cast the return value of `malloc`. It prevents the compiler from screaming in pain due to completely wrong types.

Comment: Also `int a` and `a = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int))` are not compatible with the functions you defined. `a` is not a good match for `int**a`. Even if it was `int*a` (which would match the `malloc` part) wouldn't be valid argument for your functions.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic 2D n x n array is allocated using this code:

```
int (*a)[n] = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
```

It means: Declare `a` as pointer to an integer array with `n` element and allocate `n` of those arrays (i.e. `n * sizeof *a`). In that way it ends up with `n x n` integers.

So a full version of your code could be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read(int n, int a[][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }

}
void show(int n, int a[][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("number of lines and columns:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n < 1) exit(1);
    int (*a)[n] = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    read(n, a);
    show(n, a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

**note** : To keep it simple I skipped all check of `scanf` return values. In real code, the `scanf` return value shall always be checked.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with allocating a block using `malloc ( n * n * sizeof *a);`
The address of the block must be assigned to a pointer `int *a`
Elements can be accessed by `(a + i * n + j)` or `a[i * n +j]`

```
void read(int *a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (a + i * n + j));
            // scanf("%d", &a[i * n + j]);
        }
}

void show(int *a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", *(a + i * n + j));
            // printf("%d", a[i * n + j]);
        }
}


int main()
{
    int n = 0, opt = 0, *a = NULL;
    printf("number of lines and columns:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = malloc ( n * n * sizeof *a);
    while (1)
    {...
```

Comment: you had the answer i was actually looking for, thank you! <3